# Query with "limit" not returning results

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query:

```
select * 
  from (SELECT "MYTABLE".* FROM "MYTABLE" ORDER BY "COMPANY" ASC, "SURNAME" ASC) 
 where ROWNUM between 0 and 20
```

Which works like expected, but when I try to fetch the next 20 Records with:

```
select * 
  from (SELECT "MYTABLE".* FROM "MYTABLE" ORDER BY "COMPANY" ASC, "SURNAME" ASC) 
 where ROWNUM between 20 and 40
```

The result-set is empty? Why is this and what can I do to get the next 20 records?

Comment: Are you sure there are results after 20? If you get your results between 0 and 40 do you get 40 results?

Comment: Because you are not using ROWNUM properly: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: yes 40 results are returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'd have to nest rownum , as rownum is only incremented once the row is fetched. so saying where `rownum > 1` will never return a row. 
eg

```
select *
  from (select a.*, rownum r 
          from (select mytable.*
                  from mytable 
                 order by company asc, surname asc) a
         where rownum <= 40
       )
 where r >= 20
 order by r;
```

or you can use the `row_number()` analytic

```
select *
  from (select mytable.*, row_number() over (order by company asc, surname asc) rn
          from mytable) 
 where rn between 20 and 40
 order by rn;
```